# Unable to download spring security related maven dependencies for a Cloud Foundry application

Tags: cloudfoundry-uaa, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploying CF application available as the part of OpenSap course from this GitHub URL https://github.com/raepple/cfsectest.git . When I do maven clean install, I got the error as in the screenshot. It tells that it is unable to download some maven dependencies.

Any solution to this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a partial answer as these Maven dependencies are not available no longer. Please refer this [blog](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-bulletinboard-ads/issues/11) for an alternative fix.